# Event Handlers in My Converter App Are Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

This is the code I have so far:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Double X;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text != "")
        X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        X *= 0.001;
        label3.Text = "metros";
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        X *= 0.62;
        label3.Text = "milhas";
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        label3.Text = "quilómetros";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        X *= 3280,84;
        label3.Text = "pés";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        X *= 0.17998560115190784737;
        label3.Text = "léguas";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(X);

    }
```

This is how the window looks like:
[image: Active Form]

What these do is, when you insert a value on textBox1 (the red one on the middle left of the window), you then select the measurement from the buttons on the right, this will convert the introduced value to kilometres and store it in the variable X and write the chosen measurment on a label to the right of the textBox1.

When you press the "Converter" button, (for now) I wanted the textBox2 to show X, however, this only works when I press "metros" or "pés", if I choose one of the other buttons for the conversion it will simply do nothing...

Does someone have any idea of what's wrong?

And also, side question, how do you select items from the comboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `if` statements only execute the very next statement if their condition is met:

```
if(textBox1.Text != "")
X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);  // only run if 'if' is true
X *= 0.001;                           // always run
label3.Text = "metros";               // always run
```

The if is associated with the next line. If you want all of the following code to be associated with the `if`, then you need to open a block:

```
if(textBox1.Text != "")
{
   X = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
   X *= 0.001;
   label3.Text = "metros";
}
```

To help guard against this, I would advise adopting a consistent style for single-line `if` statements:

```
if (something) SomeStatement(); // same line

if (something)
    SomeStatement(); // indented

if (something)
{
    SomeStatement(); // single statement block
}
```

It's possible some of your buttons are not working because the link between the event handler methods and the events has been broken. You should open the designer and ensure that each of the buttons has a `Click` handler assigned.

With respect to the combo-box part of your question: `ComboBox.SelectedItem` allows you to get or set the selected item. Alternatively you can use `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to get or set the index of the item that is selected.

Comment: how the hell could I have not seen that.... thank you, I could go bash my head against a wall now =)

Comment: This is a common problem. Some people guard against it by always using the braces, even for single line statements. Personally I put a single line statement on the same line as the `if`.

Comment: @Madcowe if you indent blocks then it will be much clearer. The lack of indenting is an obvious sign of what's going on. BTW VS will largely do this for you, and the details are customisable under Tools | Option | Text Editor | C#.

Comment: @Richard weird, it still gives the same problem, only "metros" and "pés" buttons work, the others simply keep textBox2 as it was, but the other 2 buttons work perfectly... I have no idea what could be wrong

Comment: @Madcowe: check that the event handlers are bound to the buttons in the Events section of the properties window.

Comment: I dont see an event section on the properties window, and you mean the 5 buttons right?

Comment: @Madcowe: OK, click on a button that's not working, go to the Properties window. You should see a little icon that looks like a lightning bolt (tooltip of 'Events') -- click that. Scroll down to the `Click` event. Make sure that the method listed beside it is the one you want to run when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Madcowe also i think there is a better way to test for Empty Text like if(!String.isNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)) ,and put o TextBox1 on KeyPress event if {(!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) e.handled = true;}

Comment: well, I dont know what I did, or if I actually did something to it, but it is now working though. thanks for the help anyway ;)